# Class Not Found Error Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, class, ide

I've tried just about everything I can think of to try and correct this error but nothing is working. Maybe it would just be easier to start a new project.

Please help if you have a reasonable and workable solution. I don't have enough time to work on my projects sometimes because I have a family to tend to as well.

Here is the logcat output

```
01-24 14:48:56.831: E/AndroidRuntime(221): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
01-24 14:48:56.891: E/AndroidRuntime(221): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.brndev.gummypopcomplete/com.brndev.gummypopcomplete.GummyPopRunActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.brndev.gummypopcomplete.GummyPopRunActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@45c77a18
01-24 14:48:56.891: E/AndroidRuntime(221):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
01-24 14:48:56.891: E/AndroidRuntime(221):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
01-24 14:48:56.891: E/AndroidRuntime(221):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
01-24 14:48:56.891: E/AndroidRuntime(221):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
01-24 14:48:56.891: E/AndroidRuntime(221):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-24 14:48:56.891: E/AndroidRuntime(221):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-24 14:48:56.891: E/AndroidRuntime(221):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
01-24 14:48:56.891: E/AndroidRuntime(221):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-24 14:48:56.891: E/AndroidRuntime(221):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-24 14:48:56.891: E/AndroidRuntime(221):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
01-24 14:48:56.891: E/AndroidRuntime(221):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
01-24 14:48:56.891: E/AndroidRuntime(221):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-24 14:48:56.891: E/AndroidRuntime(221): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.brndev.gummypopcomplete.GummyPopRunActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@45c77a18
01-24 14:48:56.891: E/AndroidRuntime(221):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
01-24 14:48:56.891: E/AndroidRuntime(221):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
01-24 14:48:56.891: E/AndroidRuntime(221):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
01-24 14:48:56.891: E/AndroidRuntime(221):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
01-24 14:48:56.891: E/AndroidRuntime(221):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)
01-24 14:48:56.891: E/AndroidRuntime(221):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: It will be hard for us to find without any piece of code... Can we see your manifest? I think you forgot to declare your Activity in your manifest.

Comment: like psykhi says make sure u declare it in ur Manifest, but also if you are not using an IDE check if you are calling the proper class. If you are using an IDE like eclipse try cleaning the project, you have no idea how many of those kinds of errors have been fixed by just cleaning the project.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with psykhi. Make sure that you have declared your `GummyPopRunActivity` in the Manifest file.